# Array in Objective-C and the @Interface file

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm just starting to learn Objective-C and I'm trying to understand the code below. There are 3 files: FindLargestNumber.h, FindLargestNumber.m and main.m.

In the FindLargestNumber.h file, I was wondering if someone can explain me the signification of the `@interface NSMutableArray (FindLargestNumber)`. I was expecting to see there something like `@interface FindLargestNumber: NSObject` instead.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSMutableArray (FindLargestNumber)

- (id)largest:(NSMutableArray *)array;

@end

------------------------------------------------------------

#import "FindLargestNumber.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (FindLargestNumber)

- (id)largest:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    id currentLargest = @0;
    for (id item in array) {
        if (item > currentLargest) {
            currentLargest = item;
        }
    }
    return currentLargest;
}

@end

------------------------------------------------------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FindLargestNumber.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @1, @4, @743, @77, @0, nil];
        //NSLog(@"%@", array);
        NSLog(@"The largest value is %@", [array largest:array]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: [OffTopic] Actually the best way to find the largest value in an array is KVC: `NSArray *array = @[@1, @4, @743, @77, @0];` `NSLog(@"The largest value is %@", [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"]);`

Answer (score 0):

The NSMutableArray class (which already exists) is being extended by adding a new method named `largest:`. In Objective-C, classes are extended using categories, and here the category is named `FindLargestNumber`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html for details.

Comment: Poor terminology. A class is extended through subclassing, not categories. Categories add new methods to existing classes without subclassing.

Comment: From the Apple documentation I referenced in my answer: "A category must import the interface file for the class it extends:" The terminology is fine.

Comment: @Mark Smith, Thanks Mark!